# How to install a specific version of cocoapods repo

Tags: ios, cocoapods

This is my `Podfile`:

```
source 'https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git'
platform :ios, '8.0'
use_frameworks!

pod 'RMQClient', '~> 0.8'
```

When I try to install the repo from cocoapods with `pod install`, it installs me a new version from `pod 'RMQClient'` (the 0.9 for example).

In another `xcode project` with the same `Podfile`, I made a `pod update` and the cocoapods it update the pod repo:

> Installing RMQClient 0.9.0 (was 0.8)

How can I prevent the `cocoapods` update the pod repos when I do a update? 
How can I force to install the version I set in the `Podfile`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your error is in `~>`

Try

> `pod 'RMQClient', '0.8'`

**Update:**

Check repo tags.

A correct repo tags should be like:

[image]

And i can see that the `RMQClient` have:

[image]

Take in considerention the `v` character. *I'm not sure, but it could be the inconvenient*